# Maven source:jar Reference remain after obfuscation

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, proguard

I am using proguard-maven-plugin as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>shawn.thye</groupId>
<artifactId>shawnthye</artifactId>
<version>2.1.0</version>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Shawns-MacBook-Pro.local-releases</name>
        <url>http://localhost:8081/artifactory/release</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>com.github.wvengen</groupId>
            <artifactId>proguard-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>proguard</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <obfuscate>true</obfuscate>
                <options>
                    <option>-dontoptimize</option>
                    <option>-allowaccessmodification</option>
                    <option>-useuniqueclassmembernames</option>
                    <option>-keep public class * { public protected *; }</option>
                    <option>-keepclassmembers,allowoptimization enum * { public static **[] values(); public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String); }</option>
                </options>
                <maxMemory>1024m</maxMemory>
                <libs>
                    <lib>${java.home}/lib/rt.jar</lib>
                </libs>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**source.jar**

```
package shawn.thye.internal;

import shawn.thye.Printer;

/**
 * Created by shawnthye on 17/12/2016.
 */
public class Helper {
    public Printer getPrinter() {
        return new PrinterImpl(); /*THIS SHOULD BE new a() not new PrinterImpl()*/
    }
}
```

PrinterImpl after obfuscated

```
package shawn.thye.internal;

import shawn.thye.Printer;

class a implements Printer {
    a() {
    }

    public void print(int page) {
    }
}
```

and i run `mvn clean package source:jar deploy --settings="settings.xml"`

I have a protected `class PrinterImpl{}` renamed to `class a{}`, but the `Main` class still refer to `class InternalPrinter{}` in the generated sources.jar by `mvn source:jar`

which i have no idea, can anyone help?

Comment: you need to share the class and its usage as well as the settings.xml here.

Comment: @nullpointer the settings only contain repo setting, pom.xml is just very simple